# Without using Strings in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

How can i get the exact output of following programe with out using string, switch. Only "if and else if else" can be used.

Program:

> ```
>     Write a program that prompts the user to enter an integer for
>     today’s day of the week (Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, . . . , and Saturday is 6). Also,
>     prompt the user to enter the number of days after today for a future day and display
>     the future day of the week
> ```

Rules:

1. Zero is equal to Sunday
2. One is equal to Monday
3. Three is equal to Tuesday
4. four is equal to Wednesday
5. five is equal to Thursday
6. six is equal to Friday
7. Seven is equal to Saturaday

And the sample output should be:

> ```
>     Enter today's day: 1(press Enter)
>     Enter the number of days elapsed since today: 3(press Enter)
>     Today is Monday and the future day is Thursday
> ```

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int date,elapsed,day_of_weak,future_date;

    cout<<"Enter today's date: ";
    cin>>date;
    cout<<"Enter the number of days elapsed since today: ";
    cin>>elapsed;
    //Calculating Future date
    future_date = (date+elapsed)%7;

    if(date==0){
       cout<<"Today is "<<date<<" and the future day is "<<future_date<<endl;
    }
    if(date==1){
       cout<<"Today is "<<date<<" and the future day is "<<future_date<<endl;
    }
    if(date==2){
       cout<<"Today is "<<date<<" and the future day is "<<future_date<<endl;
    }
    if(date==3){
       cout<<"Today is "<<date<<" and the future day is "<<future_date<<endl;
    }
    if(date==4){
       cout<<"Today is "<<date<<" and the future day is "<<future_date<<endl;
    }if(date==5){
       cout<<"Today is "<<date<<" and the future day is "<<future_date<<endl;
    }
    if(date==6){
       cout<<"Today is "<<date<<" and the future day is "<<future_date<<endl;
    }
    if(date==7){
       cout<<"Today is "<<date<<" and the future day is "<<future_date<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and My output is:

```
Enter today's date: 1
Enter the number of days elapsed since today: 3
Today is 1 and the future day is 4
```

How can convert 1 in Monday and 4 into thursday. without using the strings and switches. Thanks

Comment: *with out using string* -- Exactly what do you mean by "without using string"?  How are you going to output character data if it is not a string?

Comment: Maybe using a char array?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie may be using nested loop for each possibility,

Comment: I think these "maybe's" should be clarified by the poster.  That's why the question is being downvoted.

Comment: 1 means Monday and 3 means Tuesday ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution may give you a hint to solve your issue. As you can see in the code, we provide additional function called `show_day` to re-use the code for the `today` and `future-day`.

> > Replace your if-else statements with this line:

```
cout << "Today is " << show_day(date) << "and the future day is " << show_day(future_date);
```

> And add the following function:

```
string show_day(int day){
    if(date == 0)
        return "Sunday ";
    else if(date == 1)
        return "Monday ";
    else if(date == 2)
        return "Tuesday ";
    else if(date == 3)
        return "Wednesday ";
    else if(date == 4)
        return "Thursday ";
    else if(date == 5)
        return "Friday ";
    else
        return "Saturday ";
}
```

I hop this will help you: